How to run a regression model with conditional statements?
New to R.
Hoping to code a regression model with an outcome for 12 month X data value adjusted for by 0 month X data value. I have a column that contains data values X (continuous variable) at 0,6, 12 month time points. How can I write a regression that conditionally represents 12 month X, adjusted for by 0 month X?
reg dataX12 age dataX0
I have tried subset and if functions without success.
